Laravel eloquent, consulta en campo con modelo diferentes (polimorfica)
Tengo una tienda que tiene una tabla de orders (id, user_id, items, total, addressable_id, addresable_type)
Necesito que al hacer una consulta en order me devuelva la direccion dependiendo el modelo que este en addresable_type
adicionalmente tengo 3 tablas (sepomex, easy_address, word_address), dependiendo en donde viva el comprador se usa cada tabla, easy_address se usa para los que viven en la ciudad de México, ya que contiene el nombre de las calles, sepomex se usa para el resto del país de México, ya que contiene los códigos postales, pero no las calles y word_address para el resto del mundo.
en el campo  addresable_type de la tabla orders se llena con el nombre del modelo que puede ser app\Models\EasyAddress, app\Models\Sepomex o app\Models\WordAddress y en el addressable_id el id
Creo que es una relación de uno a muchos polimórfica pero inversa?
En el modelo orders va el metodo addressable?
class Order extends Model
{
    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphMany( **que lleva aqui?** );
    }
}

Como puedo hacer paraqué al momento de generar una consulta en la tabla orders me regrese el valor de la dirección dependiendo el modelo ( Sepomex, EasyAddres o WordAdress? )

Tu tabla orders debiera tener los campos addresable_type y addresable_id. En ellos irían por ejemplo valores como
App\Models\Sepomex y 1 (ojo que el namespace App es con mayúsculas).
En La definición del modelo Order tendrías:
public function addresable(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

Y en la definición de tus modelos de direcciones tendrías:
public function orders(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'addresable');
}

